# Nested Parameter in ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Is there any way to link nested template for parameters in azure ARM templates?

```
"variables": {
        "templatelinkappinsight": "https://xxxxx.blob.net/appinsights.json"
    },
```

For example: I have parameter section defined like following, i want to do nested template linking like variables section as mention above for parameters.

```
"parameters": {
        "functionAppName": {
            "value": "test"
        },
        "applicationInsightsName": {
            "value": "test"
        },
}
```

Comment: not sure whats the question here? what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: To deploy complex solutions, you can break your template into many related templates, and then deploy them together through a main template. The related templates can be separate files or template syntax that is embedded within the main template. [Please go through the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates)